# Extension that can access geographically blocked content on websites?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome Extension that can access geographically blocked websites and the content on them.

Think of this scenario...

> I live in X country, but the website I have just visited requires you to be from A country in order to visit

Is there a Google Chrome Extension that can bypass this? Ideally I want one that can do this....

> Make it look like I am in A country

Here's the twist, I have encountered many "fast" VPN servers and proxy server extensions on Chrome, although they work sometimes they are annoyingly slow and sometimes don't work, not to mention the free VPN servers out their change the password everyday which is annoying and dumb and becomes a inconvenience for me.

These are my requirements that I **must** have for this Google Chrome extension....

- Does **not** affect your original internet speed!
- Does **not** lag up!
- Does **not** secretly log your activity on the internet!

**And finally is free, is not a trial and you don't have to pay for a monthly subscription!**

Note: Do not suggest Hola Better Internet please! It does not work for me. Also do not suggest Media Hint, although it fulfills **most** of my requirements, it is not free and I have no intentions on buying, also it use to be free but now they charge.

Any suggestions? Also if you cannot find a Google Chrome Extension but know a Windows 7 program/VPN or Proxy that can fulfill this, please add it instead. It however must fulfill the above requirements and must be free and also safe to use.

Comment: Do you own a server in country A? If not, you will most probably need to use a third-party server, making your condition "not secretly log your activity" very difficult to fulfil.

Comment: If you own a cellphone, you can use Hideman to bypass country restrictions. There is 4 hours offered, but you can get more by installing apps and just unistall them after (I use XPrivacy so it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZenMate](https://zenmate.com/). I've been using it for a few months, in it's 'rollout period'. In this period, ZenMate are offering unlimited traffic to anyone until they completely finish the extension. I don't know what the limitations will be after they stop giving unlimited traffic, but you can use this temporarily until they do so (they might be generous later on!).

Features:

- free (and always will be)
- encrypts traffic
- very simple to use - click button and change location

I haven't noticed any speed difference since I've got Zenmate, but I haven't done any technical tests on that - but trust me, it's unnoticeable (if there even is a difference).

[image]